# Press Next Button on Android Native App, no response for Appium Test

Tags: android, python, python-appium

Right now, i am using Appium with Python to write test cases on Android native app. I am very beginner, and really need some advice on how to write test cases below.And i am stuck on step2

1, input email address
2, press NEXT button on keyboard
3, input password

what i did is below
1,driver.find_element_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText").send_keys("emailaddress@emailaddress.com")
2,driver.keyevent(261)  or driver.keyevent("261")

Step1 is working prefect, but step2 never work, no response at all.
Any suggestion on how to write script to make it press NEXT?

Thank you very much

Comment: insteadd of key event can u inspect the web element of next and use find element syntax?

Answer (score 0):

try this answer :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains;
""" Instantiate the driver like: driver = driver=webdriver.Remote( ... ); """
chain = ActionChains(driver);
""" Send search key"""
chain.send_keys(u'\uE007').perform();


+--------------+---------------------+
|     KEY      |   Unicode Character |
+--------------+---------------------+
| ALT_LEFT     | \uE00A              |
| DEL          | \uE017              |
| DPAD_DOWN    | \uE017              |
| DPAD_LEFT    | \uE012              |
| DPAD_RIGHT   | \uE014              |
| DPAD_UP      | \uE013              |
| ENTER        | \uE007              |
| SHIFT_LEFT   | \uE008              |
| BACK         | \uE100              |
| ANDROID_HOME | \uE101              |
| MENU         | \uE102              |
| SEARCH       | \uE103              |
| SYM          | \uE104              |
| ALT_RIGHT    | \uE105              |
| SHIFT_RIGHT  | \uE106              |
+--------------+---------------------+
```